# split large .lst file into pieces because because readlines() cant read the full file

Tags: python

To use a wordlist (large one "16 Gb") to crack a password issue i've downliaded a file in .lst form from: https://crackstation.net/buy-crackstation-wordlist-password-cracking-dictionary.htm

So when i try to readlines() the file to split lines it only read a 69100 line even the worlist contain more than a billion line.

ex:

```
passwordlist = str(raw_input("\nEnter the path name of the password list file : "))
list = open(passwordlist, "r")
passwords = list.readlines()
list.close()
for password in  passwords:
        attack(password.replace("\n",""))
```

i need to split the file into txt pieces using python whithout reading lines such as spliting a video or an audio.

anything could help please.

Comment: @James, the tags `readlines` and `large-files` definitely seems relevant here.

Comment: im sorry, im new here.
thanx for correcting my tags.

Comment: i have found the answers of my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289859/splitting-large-text-file-into-smaller-text-files-by-line-numbers-using-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting large text file into smaller text files by line numbers using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289859/splitting-large-text-file-into-smaller-text-files-by-line-numbers-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried read in a loop? read(size) or readline()
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: yes! thanx for trying to reminding.
thats the code if you can help:
https://justpaste.it/edit/15414193/a5a3d8c5

Comment: The problem is the 'password' variable. Instead of list.readlines() loop over the file object with readlines() and check the current line. (Or use read(size) for chuncks of data.)

Comment: I've already tried this:  https://justpaste.it/edit/15414472/f0e084a6
and when i print chuncks it keep repeating the first chunk.

Comment: Actualy readlines could read more than 69100 line cause ive tried it with another wordlist and it have read more than a million line but in this wordlist it stop when it reach 69100 line no more even that the wordlist contain more than a billion line.