# How to input large data into python pandas using looping or parallel computing?

Tags: python, loops, csv, pandas, parallel-processing

I have a csv file of 8gb and I am not able to run the code as it shows memory error.

```
file = "./data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep="/", header=0, dtype=str)
```

I would like to split the files into 8 small files ("sorted by id") using python. And fianlly,have a loop so that the output file will have the output of all 8 files.

Or I would like to try parallel computing. Main goal is to process 8gb data in python pandas.  Thank you.

My csv file contains numerous data with '/' as the comma separator,

```
id    venue           time             code    value ......
AAA   Paris      28/05/2016 09:10      PAR      45   ......
111   Budapest   14/08/2016 19:00      BUD      62   ......
AAA   Tokyo      05/11/2016 23:20      TYO      56   ......
111   LA         12/12/2016 05:55      LAX      05   ......
111   New York   08/01/2016 04:25      NYC      14   ......
AAA   Sydney     04/05/2016 21:40      SYD      2    ......
ABX   HongKong   28/03/2016 17:10      HKG      5    ......
ABX   London     25/07/2016 13:02      LON      22   ......
AAA   Dubai      01/04/2016 18:45      DXB      19   ......
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Use itertools as the answer here explains https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289859/splitting-large-text-file-into-smaller-text-files-by-line-numbers-using-python

Comment: do you actually need the 8 small files or you are going to use only the final file?

Comment: only the final file

Comment: @Iris so essentially you want to sort your `csv` by id and save it to file?

Answer (score 9):

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

def processor(df):

    # Some work

    df.sort_values('id', inplace=True)
    return df

size = 8
df_split = np.array_split(df, size)

cores = 8
pool = Pool(cores)
for n, frame in enumerate(pool.imap(processor, df_split), start=1):
    frame.to_csv('{}'.format(n))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: Hey ! this is cool!! i was looking for something similar ! But i get this error, frame.to_csv(output, sep="^", index=False.format(n))
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: where, output = "/file.csv"

Comment: frame.to_csv(output, sep="^", index=False)

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 659, in next
    raise value
IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds

Comment: What inside of your processor function?

Comment: i have this code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44966816/how-to-resolve-positional-index-error-in-python-while-solving-a-condition-in-pyt

Comment: frame.to_csv(output, sep="^", index=False) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Comment: @Iris: This approach will never work in case of _** I am not able to run the code as it shows memory error.**_. Every `Process` are passed `df_split` which is a List of `pandas.DataFrame`.  And every `Process` needs his **own** Memory, therfore the Memory Footprint are multiplied with 8.

Comment: you are a savior.

Comment: you are a savior. but it is iterating over the first column again and again how I can iterate over all the rows in parallel. ... i am trying to achieve something like :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53561794/iteration-over-a-pandas-df-in-parallel

Answer (score 6):

Use the `chunksize` parameter to read one chunk at the time and save the files to disk. This will split the original file in equal parts by 100000 rows each:

```
file = "./data.csv"
chunks = pd.read_csv(file, sep="/", header=0, dtype=str, chunksize = 100000)

for it, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
    chunk.to_csv('chunk_{}.csv'.format(it), sep="/")
```

If you know the number of rows of the original file you can calculate the exact `chunksize` to split the file in 8 equal parts (`nrows/8`).

Comment: Wont this still consume too much memory though, since the entire dataframe is loaded before iterating an saving?

Comment: No. The whole point of chunking is that it does not load the entire dataframe into memory. The variable `chunks` in my answer is an iterable object which occupies virtually no memory (read more here)[http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking]. Only when you iterate through `chunks` you actually reading a chunk-sized version of the file into memory.

Answer (score 5):

pandas read_csv has two argument options that you could use to do what you want to do:

```
nrows : to specify the number of rows you want to read
skiprows : to specify the first row you want to read
```

Refer to documentation at: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

You also might want to use the das framework and it's built in [dask.dataframe](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html). Essentially, the csv file is transformed into multiple pandas dataframes, each read in when necessary. However, not every pandas command is avaialble within dask.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need all columns you may also use `usecols` parameter:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

```
usecols : array-like or callable, default None

Return a subset of the columns. [...] 
Using this parameter results in much faster parsing time and lower memory usage.
```